# Can I collect oracle database 11g R2 information using shell script?

Tags: shell, oracle11g, monitoring

I want to develop database monitoring tool. In my development, I want to use shell script to collect database information (e.g hit rate of SGA,Session,Lock,etc.). But I'm a newbie of shell script and oracle database.I used oracle database 11g R2 enterprise edition. Can I collect oracle database 11g R2 information using shell script? Can anybody share me some ideas and references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

You need to put together a bunch of SQL statements that query the relevant system views (`V$...`).

The from within the shell script you call `sqlplus` and spool the output of the statements to a text file.

Comment: Thanks Mr.a_horse_with_no_name. Could you share me some examples?

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye: examples of what?

Comment: I mean references link or some code snippet of SQL statements and shell script usages.